# RStudio session wide rounding - options(digits=x) is ignored

Tags: r

How to make RStudio (possibly the underlying R) stick to rounded x decimal places across session?

```
options(scipen=999)
options(digits=4)
options()['digits']    # does return $digits [1] 4

p <- dbinom(x=0:10, size=10, prob=0.1) 
p

#> [1] 0.3486784401 0.3874204890 0.1937102445 0.0573956280 0.0111602610 0.0014880348 0.0001377810 0.0000087480 0.0000003645 0.0000000090
#> [11] 0.0000000001
```

The `scipen` works fine as seen (clears scientific notation), but the digits... not. Clearing/restarting session and workspace makes no difference and despite running the above, it's stuck on that long format output, which is terrible for ad-hoc in-the-head calculations. I don't want to clog up the code with hundreds of unnecessary `round()` statements, especially when digits exists to resolve that.

Oddly, the `p` variable in workspace does show the 4DP rounded values! But that's no good, we need them on the console!

Have updated to latest RStudio 1.1.383 (R is also new 3.4.3) on x64 but still no joy.

I must be missing something but can't see what - anybody know why it doesn't stick?

Comment: from the help : it mentions *"**significant** digits to print when printing numeric values. It is a suggestion only."* , not actual digits. Your small numbers require more than 4 digits to represent them. `p[1:4]` works as you expect.

Comment: You're right of course @user20650 - indeed it does display the right rounding when values lie within that range (and on other code). Oddly, I have seen it round other functions to 0.0000 when real val 0.00000001 etc, but not in this case. I'd still like to ensure the specified sig digs are displayed across the board, maybe someone knows how?

Comment: Use `sprintf("%.13f", dbinom(x=0:10, size=10, prob=0.1))` if you want 4 or more significant digits everywhere.  R won't print the trailing zeros unless you force it.

Comment: BTW, this is entirely an R issue, nothing to do with RStudio.  It's just a front end, submitting code to R and displaying the output.

Comment: sprintf wrapper for C function is indeed useful @user2554330, although naturally I want to avoid, like round(), having to wrap every call - it seems unnecessary. Thanks for heads up too - yes I see that RStudio is literally just passing code to R and back. Maybe they both hoped the other would sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

Have accepted that the output is what it is - and that it's easy to fall into trap of expecting Decimal Places DP not Significant Digits SD. It would be handy to force DP through options but then many values would be blanked or plain wrong due to the high accuracy often required (minuscule p-values etc).

So best not force DP after all, and stick with SD (perhaps nice if individual vector vals as illustrated were rounded separately but is a trade-off on consistency). So all good.